# jQuery UI Datepicker and Timepicker conflict with minDate and maxDate (Error parsing the date string: Missing number at position 0)

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, timepicker, maxdate, mindate

I am using Rails `3.2.11` and am trying to use both [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) and [Timepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/), however I am facing problems when trying to use the `minDate` and `maxDate` properties of Datepicker.

My view for one page (in `HAML`), looks like this:

```
.field_section
  = f.label :date, "Date"
  %br
  = f.datepicker :date, :minDate => "-10y", :maxDate => "+1y", :dateFormat => "yy-mm-dd",
    :constrainInput => true, :showOtherMonths => true, :size => 10
```

I have `jQuery UI 1.10` and everything works perfectly.

However, in a completely separate view, i also need a timepicker, so i include the `jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js` file (version 1.20) in my `application.js`

The order of inclusion is:

1. jQuery (1.8.3)
2. jQuery UJS jQuery UI (specifically, autocomplete, datepicker and slider)
3. Timepicker

Now, loading the first view (which only has a datepicker, **not timepicker**) gives me the following error in Chrome JS console, when i click on the datepicker input:

```
Error parsing the date string: Missing number at position 0
date string = -10y
date format = yy-mm-dd
Error parsing the date string: Missing number at position 0
date string = +1y
date format = yy-mm-dd
```

Which is repeated another 5 or so times. The errors point to `jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js:1912`, which, unhelpfully is just:

```
$.timepicker.log = function(err){
    if(window.console)
        console.log(err);
};
```

Oddly, if i remove the `minDate` and `maxDate` attributes from my view, the errors go away - but i want to use these options. Any idea what is going on?

Thanks

Update:
 i have noticed if i pass `minDate` and `maxDate` as hard coded strings, ie

```
:minDate => "2000-01-01", :maxDate => "2014-01-01"
```

the errors go away. I assume this means there is an error with `dateFormat` (somewhere..?)

Comment: put a breakpoint at the log method and check the call stack

Comment: I couldnt manage to master the debugging in the JS console, but i have noticed if i pass minDate and maxDate as hard coded strings, ie `:minDate => "2000-01-01", :maxDate => "2014-01-01"` - the errors go away. I assume this means there is an error with dateFormat (somewhere). I will update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like Timepicker does not understand relative dates. I think Timepicker attempts to always override Datepicker. With `:minDate` and `:maxDate` set to relative values (ie, `+1y`) Timepicker sees a format mismatch between `+1y` and `yy-mm-dd` for example - it does not seem to first convert the `+1y` to a Date object with format `yy-mm-dd`.

The solution for me was to explicity put in Date objects:

```
:minDate => Date.today - 10.years, :maxDate => Date.today + 1.years
```

Which really isn't as nice as `+1y`

Issue raised [on Github](https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon/issues/546)