# jQueryUI datepicker maxdate

Tags: jquery, debugging

I´m using jQueryUI 1.10.3. With that version only todays date is choosable. With version 1.9.1 you could choose dates placed infinitely in future.
I presume there is a bug somewhere in my code. While in 1.10.3 the console says nothing, with 1.9.1 it threw "t.originalEvent is undefined" (in Firebug) and "cannot read property 'type' of undefined" (in Chrome dev tools).
How can I find the error specifically?

My js-code:

```
    $(function() {
        $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 3,
            minDate: 0, 
            maxDate: "+3M"
        });
        $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd.mm.yy" );
        $.datepicker.regional['de'] = {
            clearText: 'Löschen', 
            clearStatus: 'Aktuelles Datum löschen', 
            closeText: 'OK', 
            closeStatus: 'Schließen ohne Änderung', 
            prevText: '< früher', 
            prevBigText: '<<', 
            prevStatus: 'Zeige vorherigen Monat', 
            prevBigStatus: 'Zeige vorheriges Jahr',
            nextText: 'später >',
            nextBigText: '>>', 
            nextStatus: 'Zeige nächsten Monat', 
            nextBigStatus: 'Zeige nächstes Jahr', 
            currentText: 'Heute', 
            currentStatus: 'Zeige jetzigen Monat', 
            monthNames: ['Januar','Februar','März','April','Mai','Juni', 'Juli','August','September','Oktober','November','Dezember'], 
            monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mär', 'Apr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Okt', 'Nov', 'Dez'], 
            monthStatus: 'Zeige anderen Monat', 
            yearStatus: 'Zeige anderes Jahr', 
            weekHeader: 'W', 
            weekStatus: 'Woches des Jahres', 
            dayNames: ['Sonntag', 'Montag', 'Dienstag', 'Mittwoch', 'Donnerstag', 'Freitag', 'Samstag'], 
            dayNamesShort: ['So', 'Mo', 'Di', 'Mi', 'Do', 'Fr', 'Sa'], 
            dayNamesMin: ['So','Mo','Di','Mi','Do','Fr','Sa'], 
            dayStatus: 'Als ersten Tag der Woche setzen', 
            dateStatus: 'Wähle D, M d', 
            dateFormat: 'mm/tt/jj', 
            firstDay: 1, 
            initStatus: 'Wähle ein Datum', 
            isRTL: false 
        };
        $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['de']);
        $('.timepicker').timepicker({
            timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
            hourGrid: 6,
            minuteGrid: 15,
            stepMinute: 15,
            addSliderAccess: true,
            sliderAccessArgs: { touchonly: false },
            timeOnlyTitle: 'Lieferzeit',
            timeText: 'Vorschau',
            hourText: 'Stunde',
            minuteText: 'Minute',
            currentText: 'Jetzt',
            closeText: 'OK'
        });
    });
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found out the timepicker addon I´m using causes the crash. I installed another timepicker (jquery simple timepicker) and it works fine. The Bug is discussed here: [jQuery UI Datepicker and Timepicker conflict with minDate and maxDate (Error parsing the date string: Missing number at position 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14706844/jquery-ui-datepicker-and-timepicker-conflict-with-mindate-and-maxdate-error-par)